# Extracting formulas from excel sheet using python

Tags: python, excel

Is there a way for extracting formulas from an excel sheet using python?

After extensive research, I'm starting to think there isn't. I've seen answers here from 2013 and 2010 stating that there isn't one available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [openpyxl](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/) with `load_workbook('file.xlsx', data_only=False)`?